# What does やから mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence

> 清くない男女交際をするやからである

I think this translates to 'being only interested in indecent relationships'. However I am not exactly sure what the word やから means over here.

Comment: [輩]{やから} ... https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%84%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89

Comment: Yes I saw the dictionary meaning but that doesn't seem to fit in with what this sentence actually means.

Comment: What does this sentence actually mean?

Comment: Not sure, even I am confused now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 清くない男女交際をするやからである
>   (They are) folks who have indecent relationships.

This やから is 輩 in kanji, and it's a slangy noun which means "guys", "dudes", "badass", etc. Everything before やから is a relative clause that modifies やから. (You may know やから is also a kansai-ben version of だから, but that's totally irrelevant here.) If this still doesn't make sense, please add the whole context.